# Error with installing dependencies on python development environment

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

I am trying to run this assignment on my own pc: http://cs231n.github.io/assignment2/

Im not very experienced with Linux, but installed Ubuntu 14.04 and Anaconda to create a development environment for Python. When I try to install the dependencies in the created virtual environment I get errors.

The command I enter on the command line:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

The message at the end of the output on the terminal is:

> ```
> error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
>
>     ----------------------------------------
> Command "/home/derk/assignment2/.env/bin/python -c "import setuptools,
> ```
>
> tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip-build-ALh008/gnureadline/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**,
>   'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-VH7dz5-record/install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/derk/assignment2/.env/include/site/python2.7/gnureadline" failed
>   with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-ALh008/gnureadline

Edit:
Mm when of the messages in the output is:

> /home/derk/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1538:
>   UserWarning:
>           Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.

But I installed this with

> sudo apt-get install gfortran libopenblas-dev liblapack-dev

which was succesful. What could be wrong here?

Comment: How much memory did you assign to VM?

Comment: I installed Ubuntu alongside Windows, so no VM

Comment: I changed scipy 0.14.1 to 0.15.1 in requirements.txt and no it works. I hope this will not have consequences and dont know why it does not work with older versions of scipy

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the solution. When running the notebook it says RuntimeError: module compiled against API version a but this version of numpy is 9